# Android Linphone InCall Align / Float Left for Two Layout XML Files. Side by Side. Before After Image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

[image: Before and After, I want to move image up.]

The attached image show a before and after image in photoshop. The before image is what I have right now and I am trying to achieve the after. Thew two component are in two separate xml files. But I cannot just move the code from one to the other, because it will crash and I don't know how to modify the backend scripts. I want to achieve this by editing both files independently. Below are the xml:

**active_call_control_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:gravity="right|top" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:gravity="right|top" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp">
    <TextView android:textSize="22.0dip" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:gravity="right|top" android:id="@id/contactNameOrNumber" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:gravity="right|top" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/callStatus" android:layout_width="30.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/pause" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_pause" />
    <Chronometer android:textSize="22.0dip" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:id="@id/callTimer" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**active_call_image_row.xml**

```
<TableRow android:gravity="left|top" android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="160dp" android:layout_height="75.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:linphone="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

So far I tried adding a layout width to both files, 400dp and 150dp, but the image still wraped.

Comment: That appears to be a ListView, thus you cannot do what you are asking. You must modify the original row layout.

Comment: Original row layout? Which one? active_call_control_row.xml or active_call_image_row.xml? Or will there be another xml that control the layout of both files?

Comment: Anyway I can overlap the two layout? I've try using negative margin top or margin bottom. Did not work...